# Is it possible to group structs for use with std::variant

Tags: c++, c++20, variant

I'm designing a class to represent data from 10+ sources using `std::variant`. Each source may have 10 different messages, so the variant will represent 100 different underlying structs.

Understandably I'd like to declare the `std::variant` without listing 100 types in the declaration:

`std::variant<Type1, Type2, Type3............................ Type100>`

I'd prefer to sub-group the 10 structs per 'source' and the `variant` consist of the groups:

`std::variant<Source1Types, Source2Types.... Source10Types>`

Is there a way to sub-group structs, for use with `std::variant`? If not, is there any other way of achieving this?

(I'm using C++20)

Comment: `std::variant` of `std::variant`. Or create trait to unpack you subgroup into a std::variant..

Comment: What does `Source1Types` look like? Or is this just a hypothetical?

Comment: @Jarod42 Ahhhh. So I declare a variant for each source, give it a variable name and then use decltype on the source's variable name in the second variant declaration?

Comment: No, you use a `typedef` defining the "variant for each source", then have a variant of all the `typedef`s. This is what a `typedef` is for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Got you, so no need for a variable name.

Comment: @Jarod42 Put it as answer and i'll accept.

Comment: It would help if you added clarity to this question on what you mean by grouping of types and what these things look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do:

```
using Source0Types = std::variant<Type0, Type1, Type2, Type3, .., Type9>;
using Source1Types = std::variant<Type10, Type11, Type12, Type13, .., Type19>;
// ..

using SourceTypeVariant = std::variant<Source0Types, Source1Types, .., Source9Types>;
```

The caveat here is that you have two levels of variant (for the visit).

You might create trait to flatten/concatenate the variants:

```
template <typename ... Vs> struct concatenate;
template <typename ... Vs> using concatenate_t = typename concatenate<Vs...>::type;

template <typename ... Ts> struct concatenate<std::variant<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::variant<Ts...>;
};

template <typename ... Ts, typename ... Us, typename ... Vs>
struct concatenate<std::variant<Ts...>, std::variant<Us...>, Vs...> :
    concatenate<std::variant<Ts..., Us...>, Vs...>
{
};
```

And so

```
using MegaVariant = concatenate_t<Source0Types, Source1Types, .., Source9Types>;
```